# Nested interfaces in PHP

Tags: php, typescript, interface

I want to interface this TypeScript model in PHP:

```
export interface Tournament {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    phases: {
        league: {
            groups: number;
            twoLegged: boolean;
        },
        playoff: {
            twoLegged: boolean;
        }
    };
}
```

And the only solution I know would be this one:

```
/**
 * @property int $id
 * @property int $name
 * @property Tournament_Phases $phases
 */
interface Tournament
{
}

/**
 * @property Tournament_Phase_League $league
 * @property Tournament_Phase_Playoff $playoff
 */
interface Tournament_Phases
{
}

/**
 * @property int $groups
 * @property bool $twoLegged
 */
interface Tournament_Phase_League
{
}
...
```

If the model grows bigger, the number of declared interfaces would grow accordingly.

Is there any other, more concise way to declare nested object interfaces?

EDIT:

There are [anonymous classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php), there is some kind of anonymous interfaces? Something like:

```
interface Tournament
{
    public $phases = new interface {
        $league= new interface {
             $groups;
             $twoLegged;
         }
        $playoff = ...;
    }
}
```

Comment: aren't Traits an option for you?

Comment: @sietse85 how can traits help in this case?

Comment: @JavierMarín are you looking for enforcement of the object property data types?

Comment: i don't exactly know what you are trying to achieves, afaik is that nested classes / interfaces are not supported by PHP

Comment: I just edited with an example

Comment: Interfaces in PHP currently are more so for defining instructions an object can perform publicly. "How can I interface with this object?", which is why properties and non-public methods are prohibited. As opposed to TypeScript interfaces, which  define the types of values of the object. Type-hinting of object properties won't be available until PHP 7.4. To accomplish the same in PHP you would need to use setter methods that have type-hinting. Like: https://3v4l.org/2RYl9  The PHPDoc tags, are subjectively supported by IDEs like PHPStorm, but are not enforced at all.

Comment: As for your edited example for anonymous classes, there's kind of a means, but not to the extent you're wanting. You can accomplish it by using `stdClass` or type-casting with `(object) array()` Like so: https://3v4l.org/9ROVO